# INSERT into table wherever update_time is latest

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a table that has data about session. I want to insert hardcoded values for every new session row added at the latest time.

for example, given this table with 3 session rows information added at

> 2/10/2019 5:15 PM

[image: table]

I want to insert ***server1***, and ***business*** values into the 3 rows (row 1-3) at the latest `UDPATE_TIME`, which in this case is

> 2/10/2019 5:15 PM

I use this query to get the latest update time:

```
$update_time = query "SELECT FORMAT(MAX([UPDATE_TIME]), 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt') AS UPDATE_TIME FROM table"| Select -ExpandProperty UPDATE_TIME;
```

and i use this insert query to insert the values:

```
query "INSERT INTO table (SERVERNAME, Business_Name) VALUES ('server1', 'business')"
```

however, as you can see its inserting on a new row (row4), and instead i want to insert in rows that are already there 1-3, so that it becomes like this:

[image: desired table]

pseudo-code of query i am looking for:

```
query "INSERT INTO table (SERVERNAME, Business_Name) VALUES ('server1', 'business') wherever $update_time
```

Comment: You want to UPDATE an existing row, not INSERT a new row I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want an update.  Something like this:

```
update [table]
    set business_name = @business_name
    where update_time = (select max(t2.update_time) from [table] t2);
```

Doing an update after the inserts seems dangerous -- different threads could be inserting data at the same time.  However this answers the question that you did ask.

Comment: interesting. whats t2?

Comment: t2 is an alias for [table] in the sub query. This lets sql server know which reference to the table you're referring to.

Comment: oh i see. so then i can have any alias name i want right? not necessarily t2

Comment: also, cant i just use the variable $updatetime i had already defined? so it would be where $updatetime

Comment: i am getting error: Must declare the scalar variable "@business". i thought this is just supposed to be a value....

Comment: AHH, that explains where the OP had the odd syntax in their other (deleted) question. Fixed the typo here

Comment: @Larnu yes haha